# Jenkins server suddenly erroring with "Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:-9805" when doing a `git remote update`

Tags: git, ssl, jenkins

We have a Jenkins server running on a Mac mini in the office and just this morning the build started failing with the following:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (2.2.3)
Installing Appirater (2.0.2)
Installing AsyncImageView (1.5.1)
Installing Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.13.1)
Installing GoogleAnalytics-iOS-SDK (3.0.7)
Installing Kiwi (2.2.4)
[!] /usr/bin/git remote update

Fetching origin
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/allending/Kiwi.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:-9805

error: Could not fetch origin
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [pod install...]
```

It doesn't just fail with that repo; it also fails with Facebook-iOS-SDK, e.g.

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk.git/': Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to github.com:-9805
```

And also the various other dependencies listed there, like AFNetworking.

It also seems to be inconsistent since it appeared to resolve itself for about half an hour before it started happening yet again.

The DNS server was migrated about two weeks back, but this is the first time this error this has come up so I doubt it's that. But I'm not sure what else it could be. Any ideas?